# LWJGL not running on Mac

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am apart of a project and we are making a game. For our graphics, we are using LWJGL. The program runs without any problem on everyone else in the group except for me. I assume it has something to do with Mac settings.

I downloaded LibJDX and created my own project but this doesn't run either. These are the errors I get.

```
    [LwjglApplication] Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/q0/gh911rrs3pg1k241bzwk60jw0000gn/T/libgdxmichellefilipaa/f7649394/liblwjgl.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/q0/gh911rrs3pg1k241bzwk60jw0000gn/T/libgdxmichellefilipaa/f7649394/liblwjgl.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/q0/gh911rrs3pg1k241bzwk60jw0000gn/T/libgdxmichellefilipaa/f7649394/liblwjgl.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /private/var/folders/q0/gh911rrs3pg1k241bzwk60jw0000gn/T/libgdxmichellefilipaa/f7649394/liblwjgl.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2383)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALLwjglAudio.<init>(OpenALLwjglAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.createAudio(LwjglApplication.java:282)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:71)
    at com.university.maastricht.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:13)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 258ms
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.Sys
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:643)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:125)
19:43:27: Task execution finished ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
```

This is what my configurations look like. Any advice would be great. Thank you
[image: Screenshot of my configurations]

I have a MacBook Air 2020, Apple M1 chip, macOS Big Sur 11.3.1.

Comment: Are you on arm64 or x86_64?

Comment: @BasilBourque It is a MacBook Air 2020, Chip Apple M1, Mac OS Big Sur version 11.3.1

Comment: @Siguza I don't know what that is tbh 

Comment: @KaiBurjack I suggest you make an Answer of that Comment so this page can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @Michelle Post details as edits to your Question, rather than as a Comment.  I made that edit for you today.

Comment: @Michelle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1 and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture

Comment: @KaiBurjack no need for the slander 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 means arm cpu arch. LibGDX does not yet support arm on Mac because there hasn't been an LWJGL 3 release supporting that. See github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6084